# Duplicate log4j Logging

Tags: java, spring, logging, log4j

I have the following log4j.xml file in my classpath:

```
<appender class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender" name="Console">
    <param name="Threshold" value="info" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param value="%d %-5p [%t] %C (%F:%L) - %m%n" name="ConversionPattern"/>
    </layout>
    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
      <param value="info" name="LevelMax"/>
      <param value="info" name="LevelMin"/>
    </filter>
</appender>

<logger name="de.scm.cci.importer">
    <level value="info"/>
</logger>

<logger name="com.mchange">
    <level value="info"/>
</logger>
<logger name="jdbc">
    <level value="error"/>
</logger>
<logger name="org.hibernate">
    <level value="info"/>
</logger>
<logger name="org.springframework">
    <level value="info"/>
</logger>

<root>
    <level value="INFO"/>
    <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
</root>
```

Here are the first few lines of output:

```
log4j: Trying to find [log4j.xml] using context classloader sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@7220722.
log4j: Using URL [file:/opt/app/cci/CCIImporter/jar/log4j.xml] for automatic log4j configuration.
log4j: Preferred configurator class: org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator
log4j: System property is :null
log4j: Standard DocumentBuilderFactory search succeded.
log4j: DocumentBuilderFactory is: org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
log4j: debug attribute= "true".
log4j: reset attribute= "false".
log4j: Threshold ="null".
log4j: Retreiving an instance of org.apache.log4j.Logger.
log4j: Setting [de.scm.cci.importer] additivity to [true].
log4j: Level value for de.scm.cci.importer is  [info].
log4j: de.scm.cci.importer level set to INFO
log4j: Retreiving an instance of org.apache.log4j.Logger.
log4j: Setting [com.mchange] additivity to [true].
log4j: Level value for com.mchange is  [info].
log4j: com.mchange level set to INFO
log4j: Retreiving an instance of org.apache.log4j.Logger.
log4j: Setting [jdbc] additivity to [true].
log4j: Level value for jdbc is  [error].
log4j: jdbc level set to ERROR
log4j: Retreiving an instance of org.apache.log4j.Logger.
log4j: Setting [org.hibernate] additivity to [true].
log4j: Level value for org.hibernate is  [info].
log4j: org.hibernate level set to INFO
log4j: Retreiving an instance of org.apache.log4j.Logger.
log4j: Setting [org.springframework] additivity to [true].
log4j: Level value for org.springframework is  [info].
log4j: org.springframework level set to INFO
log4j: Level value for root is  [INFO].
log4j: root level set to INFO
log4j: Class name: [org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender]
log4j: Setting property [threshold] to [INFO].
log4j: Parsing layout of class: "org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"
log4j: Setting property [conversionPattern] to [%d %-5p [%t] %C (%F:%L) - %m%n].
log4j: Setting property [levelMax] to [INFO].
log4j: Setting property [levelMin] to [INFO].
log4j: Adding filter of type [class org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter] to appender named [Console].
log4j: Adding appender named [Console] to category [root].
2014-02-25 13:20:25,534 INFO  [main] de.scm.cci.importer.RunTest (RunTest.java:21) - Starting loop mode
2014-02-25 13:20:25,537 INFO  [main] de.scm.cci.importer.RunTest (RunTest.java:24) - Started...
PERSISTENCE LOADING
2014-02-25 13:20:25,767 INFO  [main] org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext (AbstractApplicationContext.java:513) - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@52545254: startup date [Tue Feb 25 13:20:25 CET 2014]; root of context hierarchy
233 [main] INFO org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext  - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@52545254: startup date [Tue Feb 25 13:20:25 CET 2014]; root of context hierarchy
2014-02-25 13:20:25,877 INFO  [main] org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader (XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:316) - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [de/scm/cci/backend/public/spring-config.xml]
```

As soon as spring starts loading, each line of the output is being doubled:

```
2014-02-25 13:20:25,767 INFO  [main] org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext (AbstractApplicationContext.java:513) - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@52545254: startup date [Tue Feb 25 13:20:25 CET 2014]; root of context hierarchy
233 [main] INFO org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext  - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@52545254: startup date [Tue Feb 25 13:20:25 CET 2014]; root of context hierarchy
```

I am totally clueless, where the second line comes from.

EDIT:
Weird enough: I am getting WARN Messages despite the fact i set all possible threasholds and stuffs to INFO only...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you only have one appender declared, and the formats of the duplicated logs are **not** the same, it seems clear that you have multiple logging frameworks going at the same time:

- log4j in your own code
- commons-logging inside of Spring

What you need to do is:

- Remove the commons-logging dependency from your classpath. If you are using maven, you have to exclude the commons-logging jar from *every Spring module*.
- Add jcl-over-slf4j to your classpath

Maven example (how to remove commons-logging): **Note: You need this exclusion syntax in every single Spring dependency**

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
  <version>${spring.version}</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Maven example (how to add slf4j, you may already be doing this):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.7</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.7</version>
</dependency>
```

If you are not using Maven, let me know and I'll try to help with your specific environment.

Comment: Well, that seemed to do the trick! I am currently not yet using maven, and removed the commons-logging jar from the classpath. The jcl-over-sl4j isn't currently there, may this cause a problem? I can't fully test right now, maybe end of the week.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a problem if you're using basic log4j, but if you are trying to use log4j over slf4j you will need the jcl-over-slf4j package.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Framework does not use log4j directly - it uses commons-logging.

It's behaviour will depend on what other logging implementations are in your application class path.

What logging related jars are in your class path?

Comment: Ok, how do i proceed from here? I understand, that i have different logging mechanism mixed up. I assume i have to configure commons-logging as well and see where that goes?